# Get google and yandex search results

Tags: parsing

I want to parse google and yandex search results for my little website analyzer utility.
so i should send hundreds requests per minute. What is good practice for this issue?
Is google search api a good way?

Comment: **If you need Yandex search results, use this [python library](https://code.google.com/p/py-ya-xml/) which utilises [Yandex XML search API](http://xml.yandex.com/).**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Google Search API may not be used for bots. Google will block your utility if you request too much searches.

http://code.google.com/apis/ajaxsearch/terms.html

> You agree that when using the Service, You will not, and will not permit users or other third parties to:
>
> Use any robot, spider, site search/retrieval application, or other device to retrieve or index any portion of Google Search Results or to collect information about users for any unauthorized purpose;